# Some of the cultures provided to connect from the Skill are not available or aren't supported by your VA

Tags: botframework, bots

I followed along the virtual assistant template tutorial (C#) to add a skill to my bot,but when I try connect skill to the assistant, it errors out with the following error. I am using the botskills@1.0.14.
My virtual assistant is deployed in all the languages mentioned in the manifest.[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please update your question with your `manifest-1-1.json`?

Answer (score 1):

Your `botskills connect` command needs to include [the `--languages` flag](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/8e44b9dcbc64e8f97c7d8f1cfd84a87006d639df/tools/botskills/docs/commands/connect.md#options) containing all of the languages in your manifest.